# Lebesgue Measure of a given set

Tags: measure-theory

A set $ A \subset [0,1] $ is a set which is Lebesgue measurable with the property that any interval $I \subset [0,1]$ we have that:

$\lambda_\Re(A \cap I) \leq \frac{\lambda_\Re(I)}{2}$

I aim to show that  $\lambda_\Re(A) = 0$.

Any ideas for how I would go about doing this?

Comment: This sounds like an interesting problem, but where is it from?

Comment: Hint: use [Lebesgue's density theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. By outer regularity of the Lebesgue measure, let $E$ be an open set such that $A \subseteq E$ and $\lambda(E \setminus A) < \epsilon$. Write $E$ as countable union of disjoint intervals $E = \cup_n I_n$.
Then
$$ \lambda(E) - \epsilon \leq \lambda(A) = \sum_n \lambda(A \cap I_n) \leq \frac{1}{2} \sum_n \lambda(I_n) = \frac{1}{2} \lambda(E),$$ hence $\lambda(E) \leq 2\epsilon$, which implies $\lambda(A) \leq 2\epsilon$. This is true for every $\epsilon$, hence $\lambda(A) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks muchly Hugo, that was a massive help!

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer.